# Unexpected difference in JPA layer, Spring

Tags: spring, jpa, lazy-loading

Just wondering and trying to understand JPA better.
For a webservice we offer 2 ways of throwing requests to, SOAP and Rest (Json).
For some reason i dont understand there is a difference in how lazy loading is handled. Can some one explain why there is a difference in the debugging result in the following scheme?

[image: SOAP&REST msg request, debugged]

In the debugging is a difference in how the Cast is loaded of the Actor, i cant explain this.

The data classes:

Actor Table Entity

---

[image: Actor Table Entity]

Actor DTO:

---

[image: Actor DTO]

Comment: got to love the community.. within 2 seconds a -1 vote. Did you even read the post? or bother to add comment whats wrong?

Comment: I don't understand either. I mean.. for once, somebody has put actual effort into their question. Have my up-vote!

Comment: I guess that in the SOAP side the mapper tries to manage also the `Set<Role> cast` element; this will generate the `LazyInitializationException` when you write `mapper.map(actorDTO, Actor.class)`

Comment: First i was also looking at the mapping part. Thats why i put the debugger straight after the repository call. Which now shows that the Data Entity got a difference, before touching my written logic.

Comment: Put code as text. Images cannot by copied, compiled by helpers etc, are unusable . Downvote seems fair